# Match exact string with only one letter in array

Tags: elasticsearch

I've this json from elastic :

```
"_source":{
  "secteurs":[
     "TEST-A",
     "B",
  ]
}
```

And this request :

```
{"query":{"match":{"secteurs":{"query":"A"}}}}
```

I don't understand why one object with "TEST-A" is returned. I want only the "A" secteurs, not the "TEST-A"

I've try with "query_string", it's the same result.

Mapping :

```
"secteurs":{
   "type":"text",
   "fields":{
      "keyword":{
         "type":"keyword",
         "ignore_above":256
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: please add your mapping for `secteurs`. I suspect it is `standard analyser` behaviour

Comment: Execute this `http://host:port/indexName/_mapping`

Comment: Yes thank. I've add the mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, As I suspected. It is the behaviour of `standard analyser`.

When you index `TEST-A`, it will be stored as

```
 {
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "test",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "a",
            "start_offset": 5,
            "end_offset": 6,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Hence it matches `a`.

So to solve your problem, you can use the below

```
{"query":{"match":{"secteurs.keyword":{"query":"A"}}}}
```

Note: `keyword` is not_analyzed version of the data. So case sensitive too.